# Dynamic Function Mapping

Tags: c#, generics, functional-programming

I would like to define the following two functions:

```
void Map<T>(Func<T, string> mapper);

T Call<T>(string value);
```

Map needs to store the function that turns a string into a result of type T so that when the "Call" function is called with a type T and a string the appropriate function can be looked up and called.

I was thinking that map could store the function in a dictionary of type `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>` and then Call could do the casting to the appropriate type but I'm unable to get that to work. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first type argument of `Func` is the *input*, the second the output: `Func<in T, out TResult>` -- so you need `Func<string, T>`.

(The MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) uses `Func<string, string>` a fair bit which is annoying.)

Also, the dictionary can't use the type argument `T` as that's different for each element in the dictionary. Rather, use the superclass of `Func<T, TResult>` which is `Delegate`.

This should work:

```
    Dictionary<Type, Delegate> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Map<T>(Func<string, T> mapper)
    {
        dictionary[typeof(T)] = mapper;
    }

    public T Call<T>(string value)
    {
        var func = dictionary[typeof(T)] as Func<string, T>;
        return func.Invoke(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do something like this (there should be a better way, but I can't see it right now):

```
Dictinary<Type, object> _funcDict = ...;

void Map<T>(Func<T, string>mapper)
{
    _funcDict[typeof(T)] = mapper;
}

T Call<T>(string value)
{
    var func = (Func<T, string>)_funcDict[typeof(T)]
    return func(value);
}
```

What I don't like, is having an object value type in the dictionary, but I'm not sure how you can avoid it.